# How to accumulate an array by index in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have an array:

```
a = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

I want to add some other array into each index of a, while the index can appear more than one times. I want to get the some of each index. I write:

```
a[np.array([1,2,2,1,3])] += np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
```

but get a to be:

```
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

But what I want is to get:

```
array([0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0])
```

How to implement this in numpy without for loop?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using pure `numpy`, AND avoiding a for loop:

```
np.add.at(a, np.array([1,2,2,1,3]), np.array([1,1,1,1,1]))
```

Output:

```
>>> a = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0])
>>> np.add.at(a, np.array([1,2,2,1,3]), np.array([1,1,1,1,1]))
>>> a
array([0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0])
```

Please note, this does in-place substitution. This is what is desired by you, but it may not be desired by future viewers. Hence the note :)

Comment: Awesome.  I even looked at `np.add.reduceat` but I haven't spent too much time with the `ufunc` methods so I don't know most of them.  The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) here is even perfect ... "For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to a[indices] += b, except that results are accumulated for elements that are indexed more than once"

Comment: Thanks， that's what exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just iterate yourself. Something like:

```
for i in [1,2,2,1,3]:
    a[i] += 1
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to avoid for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a clever numpy vectorized way to do this... the best I can come up with is:

```
>>> indices = np.array([1,2,2,1,3])
>>> values = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
>>> a = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0])
>>> for i, ix in enumerate(indices):
...   a[ix] += values[i]
... 
>>> a
array([0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid for loop.

Comment: @maple -- I understand that, but I don't know of a way to do it.  Of course, that isn't to say that there _isn't_ a way to do it (though there might not be).  In any event, sometimes having an example of correct (working) code is enough to illuminate the problem for others to take a better crack at it.

Comment: @maple Check my answer if you're curious to know of a way to do it. Thanks. Though I completely agree with giving examples to solve problems in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like (assuming for each index there is a correlated value):

```
a = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0])
idxs = np.array([1,2,2,1,3])
vals = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
for idx, val in zip(idxs,vals):
    a[idx] += val
```